# Symfony2: How to make fetch joins inside 'createQueryBuilder' in the entity widget

Tags: symfony, doctrine, widget, entity

i have the following setup in my symfony form type for an entity widget:

```
$builder->add('work_unit', 'entity', array(
        'class' => 'TestProjectBundle:WorkUnit',
        'property' => 'fullname',
        'query_builder' => function (EntityRepository $er) use ($user_id) { 
            return $er->createQueryBuilder('wu')
            ->leftJoin('wu.work_category', 'wc')
            ->leftJoin('wu.workers', 'w')
            ->where('w.id = :worker_id')
            ->orderBy('wc.name, wu.name')
            ->setParameter('worker_id', $user_id); },
        'expanded' => false,
        'multiple' => false,
        'empty_value' => '',
    ));
```

The two joins are not fetching joins, which means that still lazy loading is required to access some properties from 'wu.work_category'.

How can i achieve that the joins are fetching joins? I googled a lot of pages but cannot find a example.
Any help would be fine :-)

Answer (score 1):

Just add a select clause:

```
$qb->select('we, wc, w');
```

Comment: 'query_builder' => function (EntityRepository $er) use ($user_id) { 
                return $er->createQueryBuilder('wu')
                ->select('wc, w')
                ->leftJoin('wu.work_category', 'wc')
                ->leftJoin('wu.workers', 'w')
                ->where('w.id = :worker_id')
                ->orderBy('wc.name, wu.name')
                ->setParameter('worker_id', $user_id); },

is unfortunately not working and produces this error:line 0,col -1 near 'SELECT wc, w': Error:Cannot select entity through identification variables without choosing at least one root entity alias